# Retrieve outlook photo programmatically without requiring end user to sign in

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, azure, outlook

We are building an internal application that displays monthly award winner (employees) photo. I thought we will retrieve outlook photo using Outlook REST API to not reinvent the wheel.

What I discovered after a few hours analysis is, if we use the API, we will have to direct user to MS login form for obtaining permission.

I was able to retrieve my own photo but had to login via MS login page. I reviewed various link and answers but could not find a simple way (e.g. API) that does not require end user to log in explicitly to fetch the employee's picture.

**Question:**

I understand MS is worried about security and need permission to be granted by end user but can i avoid login page somehow?

**Additional Information:**

The internal application is ASP.NET MVC web app deployed in Azure and connected to AD. So the user already logs in once using AD credential. When they see the  dashboard UI, on it last month winner photos to be displayed (this is where I hope to fetch employee photo programmatically in the background).

Here is a snapshot where MS says login screen is essential:

[image]

Read or tried following:

[How to get user's exchange/outlook/office365 photo?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34069979/how-to-get-users-exchange-outlook-office365-photo)

https://graph.microsoft.io/en-us/docs/get-started/aspnetmvc

https://msdn.microsoft.com/office/office365/APi/photo-rest-operations

**Update (after a day analysis)**

I have now tried all possible (based on research) ways to get the user photo from outlook by a API app (no UI, can be called by a http non-browser client). None of these allows me to get the photo by configuring app with required permission but without required user intervention or credentials.

I am thinking to build a Web API App that will return a employee image to all calling internal applications. Since this is an App running in Azure, i am thinking I can give it required access to Azure AD & Outlook, so it can read outlook photo of a employee. Since none of below method works for API app, i might have to copy all employee images in a folder and return from this static folder (will not be in Sync with outlook).

Am I missing something?

1. Exchange Web Services (EWS): Used GetUserPhoto operation like so:

https://www.outlook.com/ews/exchange.asmx/s/GetUserPhoto?email=shailendra.birthare@xyz.com&size=HR240x240

Works for all users but requires AD credentials to be supplied in web request otherwise return 401 (Unauthorized).

2. Exchange Web Services (EWS Managed API and/or REST API): Same as #1, need to provide AD username and password.
3. Outlook REST API : See #4
4. Office 365 Unified API:

Both #3 and #4 - The user will be presented with a sign in screen that displays the name of the app. Once they sign in, if it is their first time using the app, the user will be presented with a list of the app permissions the app requires and asked to allow or deny. Assuming they allow the required access, the browser will be redirected to the redirect URI specified in the initial request.

So ultimately all options needs either valid AD credentials (can't be provided by an API app) or require user to sign in and provide permission (again not possible for a http non-browser client).

Comment: In our enviroment the outlook photo source is actually active directory. Have checked for a ad property called thumbnailphoto ?

Comment: As I understand, user photo is available in our Azure AD, we will need us one of the ways i listed above to fetch the photo. Please provide more details if you are suggesting there is another way fetching outlook photo from Azure AD without authentication by user.

Comment: Change your App Pool in IIS to use a account that has read-only access to Azure AD or When you create your [Directory Entry](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bw8k1as4(v=vs.110).aspx) object specify credentials in your .cs This will give you access and doesnt present the end users with any credential prompt.

Answer (score 1):

If your user is not signed in, then your app itself must have the rights to get the photos from any user. Quoting from documentation for the Get Photo operation:

> Required scope Use one of the following scopes to get the photo of the
>   specified user, who can be the signed-in user:
>
> **user.readbasic.all**
>
> **user.read.all**
>
> **user.readwrite.all**
>
> You can also use
>   the following scope to get the photo of specifically the signed-in
>   user:
>
> user.read
>
> user.readwrite

Your app just needs one of the bolded permissions. Allow it to read all users, and it can authenticate using its client id and secret, without an authenticated user.

Comment: Thanks for your response. These permission are given from config file but the app still require user to login and provide permission explicitly. Please see my update above.

Answer (score 0):

As juunas mentioned that we can use `client id, tenant id, secret` to authenticate without an authenticated user. More details steps about how to registry AD App and assign role to application, please refer to [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-group-create-service-principal-portal). After that we can get `tenantId, appId, secretKey` from the Azure Portal. Then we can use [Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory SDK](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory) to get token for api authentication.

```
var subscriptionId = "Your subscrption";
var appId = "Registried Azure Application Id";
var secretKey = "Secret Key";
var tenantId = "tenant Id";
var context = new AuthenticationContext("https://login.windows.net/" + tenantId);
ClientCredential clientCredential = new ClientCredential(appId, secretKey );
var tokenResponse = context.AcquireTokenAsync("https://management.azure.com/", clientCredential).Result;
var accessToken = tokenResponse.AccessToken;
```

[image]